# plsql oracle parent child

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle9i

I have a parent-child relationship in an Oracle 9i database-table

like:

```
parent | child  
1      | 2  
2      | 3
2      | 4
null   | 1
1      | 8
```

I have an absolute parent (e.g. child 1) and i need a csv list or resultset of all childs of this parent.

Comment: What is your problem: how to do the hierarchical query, how to format it as .CSV file, or both?

Answer (score 2):

Using SYS_CONNECY_BY_PATH will give you the whole hierarchy comma separated:

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(parent, ',') "PATH" 
  FROM table 
 START WITH child = 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR child = parent;
```

Further options [here](http://www.psoug.org/reference/connectby.html)

Answer (score 0):

We just moved off Oracle but I wrote this procedure for you in SQL Server (they should be very similar minus the CURSOR declarations).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowRelationships
@parent AS int
AS
 PRINT 'Parent =  ' + CAST(@parent AS varchar(3))

 DECLARE @child AS int;
 DECLARE cur_children CURSOR
 FOR
  SELECT child
  FROM PCREL
  WHERE parent = @parent;

 OPEN cur_children;
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_children INTO @child;

 IF (@child IS NULL)
 BEGIN
  PRINT CAST(@parent AS varchar(3)) + ' has no children...';
 END

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  PRINT 'Child = ' + CAST(@child AS varchar(3))

  FETCH NEXT FROM cur_children INTO @child;
 END

 CLOSE cur_children;
 DEALLOCATE cur_children;


 SELECT TOP 1 @child = child
 FROM PCREL
 WHERE parent = @parent;

 EXECUTE ShowRelationships @child;

GO
```